# Huge performance hit for inlining sync method into async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a simple performance test, that indirectly calls `WriteAsync` many times. It performs reasonably as long as `WriteAsync` is implemented as shown below. However, when I inline `WriteByte` into `WriteAsync`, performance degrades by about factor 7.

(To be clear: The **only** change that I make is replacing the statement containing the `WriteByte` call with the body of `WriteByte`.)

Can anybody explain why this happens? I've had a look at the differences in the generated code with Reflector, but nothing struck me as so totally different as that it would explain the huge perf hit.

```
public sealed override async Task WriteAsync(
    byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var writeBuffer = this.WriteBuffer;
    var pastEnd = offset + count;

    while ((offset < pastEnd) && ((writeBuffer.Count < writeBuffer.Capacity) ||
        await writeBuffer.FlushAsync(cancellationToken)))
    {
        offset = WriteByte(buffer, offset, writeBuffer);
    }

    this.TotalCount += count;
}
```

```
private int WriteByte(byte[] buffer, int offset, WriteBuffer writeBuffer)
{
    var currentByte = buffer[offset];

    if (this.previousWasEscapeByte)
    {
        this.previousWasEscapeByte = false;
        this.crc = Crc.AddCrcCcitt(this.crc, currentByte);
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte ^ Frame.EscapeXor);
        ++offset;
    }
    else
    {
        if (currentByte < Frame.InvalidStart)
        {
            this.crc = Crc.AddCrcCcitt(this.crc, currentByte);
            ++offset;
        }
        else
        {
            currentByte = Frame.EscapeByte;
            this.previousWasEscapeByte = true;
        }
    }

    writeBuffer[writeBuffer.Count++] = currentByte;
    return offset;
}
```

Comment: what is the platform here? winforms? console? service? wpf? mvc? wcf? it matters, because `async` uses the sync-context (by default), and the sync-context is different between technologies.

Comment: Can u give bit detail about your's application.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: The method is indirectly called from a .NET 4.5 async unit test. I'm not sure whether this has anything to do with the sync-context, because writeBuffer.FlushAsync is called only very rarely (once for ~1024 revolutions of the while loop).

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I've also tested this with a Console application (which simply references the unit test dll and calls the test), with roughly the same result.

Comment: Assuming that you introduced several local variables while inlining, and assuming that this is a microbenchmark, the difference could be due to the indirection for local variables in an `async` method (they are pulled out into a "state" object).

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: It is a microbenchmark in the sense that >95% of the time is spent in WriteAsync method and the methods it calls.

Comment: @AndreasHuber: A microbenchmark is when you're trying to measure something that takes a very small amount of time. "Factor of 7" and "95%" are not meaningful without a baseline. E.g., is the method going from 0.0001 to 0.0007 seconds or from 0.1 to 0.7 seconds?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: It's ~260ms vs. ~1800ms.

Comment: Could you include the code you're using to measure the method?

Comment: @svick: I could include the short top method but I suspect it would be meaningless for you, as the WriteAsync method is called indirectly through several layers. Moreover, I don't understand why the calling code would matter? All it effectively does is call the WriteAsync method many times. Again, the *only* change between the two runs is the inlining of the WriteByte method, everything else is identical.

Comment: @AndreasHuber Because the same code could perform differently under different conditions. And because something else (like the size of the buffer) might affect the performance as well.

Comment: @svick: "Because the same code could perform differently under different conditions." I don't understand, the conditions are exactly the same for both runs. Same calling code, same buffer sizes, same everything. The only difference is the inlining of WriteByte.

Comment: @AndreasHuber Yeah, but I was asking for your code because we don't know what those conditions are. Maybe the difference is so huge because you're doing something wrong in the calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` methods are rewritten by the compiler into a giant state machine, very similar to methods using `yield return`. All of your locals become fields in the state machine's class. The compiler currently doesn't try to optimize this at all, so any optimization is up to the coder.

Every local which would have sat happily in a register is now being read from and written to memory. Refactoring synchronous code *out* of `async` methods and into a sync method is a very valid performance optimization -- you're just doing the reverse!

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the stack variables --> fields in a class transformation, but would never have suspected it to result in such a huge difference.

Comment: Well, it was only a theory -- it might be something else doing this entirely.